# How to segue to view controller from TabbarController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, navigationcontroller

I have a `TabbarController` with is the entry point of my app.So I want to segue for this `TabbarController` to `ViewControllerA`. I perform `performSegue(with: "identifier")`.I can reach the `ViewControllerA`,but when I reach `ViewControllerA` there is no `NavigationBar`

I tried to embed `ViewControllerA` into a `NavigationController` 1st,so the storyboard look like this

> TabbarController-> NavigationController -> ViewControllerA

By this,I can reach ViewControllerA.But I have problem in prepareForSegue method.Cause I need to include a value in the segue,now the value seem not included.

**My code in prepareForSegue is look like this :**

```
if let VcA = segue.destination.navigationController?.topViewController as? ViewControllerA {
  VcA.postId = sender as! Int
}else{
   print("cant work")
}
```

And I also tried to embed the tabbarController to a NavigationController,but in  `Xcode-> Editor -> Embed` the option is being disable.

**So my question is**

how to segue from a TabbarController to ViewController and in destination the NavigationBar is visible and can go back to previous screen?

Comment: When you embed ViewControllerA.And in NavigationController, what did you see after segue.

Comment: "I perform `performSegue(with: "identifier")`" in which file? it should be in the `ViewControllerA`...

Comment: in TabbarController bro @AhmadF

Comment: @Nitish I can embed ViewControllerA in navigationController,I already edit my question,I also can segue to ViewControllerA,but I cant get the value in segue in ViewControllerA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your storyboards looks similar to:

[image]

That's because you are calling `performSegue(with: "identifier")` in the `TabbarController` which does *not* directly connected to the segue. What you should do instead so to implement it in the first view controller  which connected to the navigation controller (`ViewControllerA`). So, it would be -for instance- something like this:

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController {
    // ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        performSegue(with: "identifier")

    }

    // ...
}
```

Thus your segue should be from `ViewControllerA` to the desired view controller.

Comment: 1st view controller is it 1st tabbar item for Tabbarcontroller?

Comment: ViewControllerA is the destination I want reach in the segue

Comment: @ken `ViewControllerA` is the first view controller which is displayed, is it correct? I added a screenshot of what I meant.

Comment: @ken so you have to connect a segue from `ViewControllerA` to the one you want to navigates to...